# C# substring html content

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, regex, string

I have data stored using tinymce with placeholders before each table

Editor view when data is entered:

```
#data1
[html table1] 

#data2
[html table2]

#data3
[html table3]
```

this is stored in database wrapped with `<p>` tag in database.

I want to strip and get html table based on parameter passed.

```
string getTable(string placeholder)
{
     string content = db.getData();

     //placeholder = data1, return html table 1 substring data from content variable
     return [html table1]; //html string

    //placeholder = data2
     return [html table2]; //html string
}
```

How can i achieve this using C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this regex might be reliable `#data2([^#]+|#(?!data))+</table>` (click to see the example)](http://regexr.com?2u0sh), but it depends on your input, it can break. [You **can't** trust regex to parse html.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/340760)

```
#data1
<table id="t1">
<tr><td>#</td></tr>
</table>

#data2
<table id="t2">
<tr><td>#</td></tr>
</table>

#data3
<table id="t3">
<tr><td>#</td></tr>
</table>
```

To match the table by its ID you [could try `<table.*?id=.t1.>([^<]|\<(?!/table))+</table>`](http://regexr.com?2u0sk).

Comment: your answer gave me another idea, i can use ids instead of placeholders, let me edit your regex for that and test it.

Comment: any idea why this regex fails to match tables on id \s*?<table\s*.*id=\"t2\">.*</table>

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a regular expression in this case. While it won't be full proof (HTML is not a regular language) but if you don't have nested tables it should work fine.

```
string strRegex = @"(?<=#data1)\s*?<table.*?>.*</table>";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Singleline);
string strTargetString = @"#data1 <table><tr><td> asdsad</td></tr></table>";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
     // myMatch.Value contains table
  }
}
```